# How to convert model trained on custom data-set for the Edge TPU board?

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, tensorflow-datasets, google-coral, tensorflow-lite

I have trained my custom data-set using the Tensor Flow Object Detection API. I run my "prediction" script and it works fine on the GPU. Now , I want to convert the model to lite and run it on the Google Coral Edge TPU Board to detect my custom objects. I have gone through the documentation that Google Coral Board Website provides but I found it very confusing. 
How to convert and run it on the Google Coral Edge TPU Board?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Without reading the documentation, it will be very hard to continue. I'm not sure what your "prediction script" means, but I'm assuming that the script loaded a .pb tensorflow model, loaded some image data, and run inference on it to produce prediction results. That means you have a .pb tensorflow model at the "Frozen graph" stage of the following pipeline:

[image: The Work Flow]
                        Image taken from [coral.ai](https://coral.ai/docs/edgetpu/models-intro/#compatibility-overview).

The next step would be to convert your .pb model to a "fully quantized .tflite model" using the post training quantization technique. The documentation to do that are given [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/performance/post_training_integer_quant). I also created a github gist, containing an example of [Post Training Quantization here](https://gist.github.com/Namburger/f44a938886ad4a0325ca2f30263fcee0). Once you have produced the .tflite model, you'll need to compile the model via the [edgetpu_compiler](https://coral.ai/docs/edgetpu/compiler/). Although everything you need to know about the edgetpu compiler is in that link, for your purpose, compiling a model is as simple as:

```
$ edgetpu_compiler your_model_name.tflite
```

Which will creates a `your_model_name_edgetpu.tflite` model that is compatible with the EdgeTPU. Now, if at this stage, instead of creating an edgetpu compatible model, you are getting some type of errors, then that means your model did not meets the requirements that are posted in the [models-requirements](https://coral.ai/docs/edgetpu/models-intro/#model-requirements) section.

Once you have produced a compiled model, you can then deploy it on an edgetpu device. Currently are 2 main APIs that can be use to run inference with the model:

- EdgeTPU API

  - [python api](https://coral.ai/docs/edgetpu/inference/#)
  - [C++ api](https://github.com/google-coral/edgetpu/tree/master/src/cpp)
- tflite API

  - [C++ api](https://coral.ai/docs/edgetpu/tflite-cpp/)
  - [python api](https://coral.ai/docs/edgetpu/tflite-python/)

Ultimately, there are many demo examples to run inference on the model [here](https://github.com/google-coral/edgetpu).

Answer (score 1):

The previous answer works with general classification models, but not with TF object detection API trained models.

You cannot do post-training quantization with TF Lite converter on TF object detection API models.

In order to run object detection models on EdgeTPU-s:

1. You must train the models in quantized aware training mode with this addition in model config:

graph_rewriter {
  quantization {
    delay: 48000
    weight_bits: 8
    activation_bits: 8
  }
}

This might not work with all the models provided in the model-zoo, try a quantized model first.

2. After training, export the frozen graph with: object_detection/export_tflite_ssd_graph.py
3. Run tensorflow/lite/toco tool on the frozen graph to make it TFLite compatible
4. And finally run edgetpu_complier on the .tflite file

You can find more in-depth guide here:
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/running_on_mobile_tensorflowlite.md

Comment: that's true, it's a more general answer as post training quantization is a much less technical approach for beginner. Here is a tutorial of mine that give an end to end object detection retrain in Colab: https://github.com/Namburger/edgetpu-ssdlite-mobiledet-retrain