# how to load your tflite model on coral dev board?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, google-coral, tensorflow-lite

I have used facenet model and converted it to tflite.
Now I want to use this repo https://github.com/vudung45/FaceRec with facenet model and implement on coral dev board?
What should be the structure of my whole folder and how to implement it?
how can i load tflite model on dev board?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a fully quantized model that meets all of the [requirements](https://coral.ai/docs/edgetpu/models-intro/#model-requirements), then the next step is to use the [edgetpu_compiler](https://coral.ai/docs/edgetpu/compiler/) to compile your model to be use with the tpu. I have a more detailed answer to similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59848664/6262757)

Comment: how to load  and use tflite model and what is input and output format?

Comment: Did you checked out my [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59847070/how-to-convert-model-trained-on-custom-data-set-for-the-edge-tpu-board/59848664#59848664)? There are multiple apis/examples to use the model. Here are some of them: https://github.com/google-coral/edgetpu/tree/master/examples

Comment: hey 
can we install tensorflow on coral dev board?

Comment: Yes , I have checked your answer. Can we install tensorflow on coral dev board?

Comment: tensorflow supports on arm platform is very limited, unfortunately, to do this you'll have to compile it yourself. Luckily, there are opensource repos that do this. You can use this released package that works for me:  https://github.com/lhelontra/tensorflow-on-arm/releases